# Use dvisvgm within standalone convert options

Tags: standalone, mactex, convert, dvisvgm

I am trying to enable "one click" generation of PDF and SVG image files from the standalone class due to having a large number of images.  This worked perfectly on my Intel Macintosh computers using the stock MacTeX installation and pdf2svg and TeXShop, however it has apparently stopped on the Apple Silicon installations, throwing 'command not found' errors.

I understand that `pdf2svg` has fallen by the wayside, and that `dvisvgm` is the preferred solution, however I am trying to work out how to make it a 'one click' solution as I used to have with `pdf2svg`.

The 'one click' command I used to use was this:

`\documentclass[crop,tikz, convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}`

however despite installing pdf2svg on the new Macs (and remembering to enable shell-escape) I get an error of

```
sh: pdf2svg: command not found
system returned with code 32512
```

Is there a way to emulate this with `dvisvgm`? Or is it always going to be a two-step process - something I'm keen to avoid with many images to manage.

Any advice/expertise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you compile from terminal?

Comment: Frustratingly that's creating another error. "Dimension too large"; Log file claims the page is more than 18feet tall...  This is rather beyond my ken at this point

Comment: OK, so two problems :) The one with the command not found sounds like a problem path, which is not automatically set for gui applications in mac. Can you try with the full path in texshop?  `/insert your full path here/pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile`

Comment: thank you :-D Rookie error in assuming that HomeBrew installs to the right place... I've only been using latex for 15 years... :$
the 18foot page? My silting preamble I've been copy/pasting for most of that 15 years! Clean that up, compilation works just fine.

Comment: Homebrew does install to the right place, mac just makes it difficult to set paths for gui apps

Comment: Fair point :-) Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!